# Maven Assembly Plugin not including Main Class in my jar

Tags: java, maven, java-web-start, maven-assembly-plugin, manifest.mf

I am using the maven assembly plugin to generate an app client that is included in an EAR.

However, it isn't including the Main Class for whatever reason. I can't figure out what is wrong.

My Maven Assembly plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>my-program</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.program.my.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>                    
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The resulting MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: me
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_20
```

EDIT:

[Here is the full Maven POM](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5rJpQdyd)

Comment: Can you explain where the main class is defined ?

Comment: In the package com.program.my in a class file called Main? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Can you show your full pom file?

Comment: Added it to the post

Comment: That's not the full pom it's only an exerpt.

Comment: Can't see any problem in your plugin config. Here's an example that works fine: https://bitbucket.org/bartswen/public-sandbox/raw/master/joystickdemo/